# using variables from classes in other classes - python

Tags: python, class, oop

I am trying to make a small RPG text-based game but decided to make it a little more complex than just simple text-based. I made a class for one of the classes you can choose (mage), and then a class for an enemy (orc). I am currently having a lot of problems with it, and one I just can't figure out how to fix it, how to use the stats (attributes) from my player class in the orc class.
I want to make the orc(s) damage the player and vice versa, but I can't seem to use the player.hp in the orc class. I tried making different things global, but it just said that the instance had been used previously, so it was not possible.

These are my two classes for mage and orc:

```
class Mage():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 100
        self.mana = 200
        self.spellpower = 1
    def fireball(self, enemy):
        dmg = randint(10 * self.spellpower,12*1.2*self.spellpower)
        dot = randint(0.5 * self.spellpower, 1.5* self.spellpower)
        self.mana -= 20
        enemy.hp -= dmg
    def attack(self, enemy):
        print(f"you have attacked {enemy}")
        fight = True
        return fight
    def flee(self,enemy):
        num = randint(1,2)
        if num == 1:
            fight = False
            print("you have succesfully fled")
            return fight
        else:
            print(f"You failed to flee. The {enemy} attacks you")
            fight = True
            attack_first = "enemyflee"
            return fight, attack_first

class Orc():
    def __init__(self, number_of):
        self.number_of = int(number_of)
        self.name = "Orc"
        self.hp = 20 * self.number_of
        self.dmg = 5 * self.number_of
    def hit(self, player):
        dmg = randint(4 * self.dmg, 6* self.dmg)
        player.hp -= dmg
        print ("The orc(s) hit(s) you")
    def appearing(self):
        if self.number_of > 1:
            print (f"{self.number_of} Orcs have appeared")
        else:
            print(f"{self.number_of} orc has appeared")
```

And this is part of my class, where I try to use the classes to make the orc attack me (The player is currently called `class1` , and named an orc `mineorc1`):

```
    while fight:
        if attack_first == "enemyflee":
            turn = "enemy"
        else:
            if attack_first() == "enemy":
                turn = "enemy"
            else:
                turn = "player"
        if turn == "enemy":
            mineorc1.hit(class1)
```

I can see how it might be confusing without the entire code, but hopefully, you can help me :)

Comment: So what happens in your case? is there any error saying that `player does not have reference to hp`, or the value does not decrease, or what's the exact problem? Also, please include the code how do you initialize both `class1` and `mineorc1`

Comment: Pick one from: [`[python] "variable from one class to another"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1+%5Bpython%5D+%22variable+from+one+class+to+another%22)

Comment: Please post a **proper** [mcve]